# define step into numpy.mgrid

Tags: python, numpy, binning

I am trying to use `numpy.mgrid` to create two grid arrays, but I want a way to insert a variable as the number of steps.

It works as expected with this code:

```
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
```

But I need to define my variable step in my own, in the line of code to generate the grid arrays, I want something like this:

```
numcols = (xmax-xmin) * 100
numrows = (ymax-ymin) * 100
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:(numcols * 1j), ymin:ymax:(numrows * 1j)]
```

But, still not working ...
Then I tried to convert the num of steps to a complex number as below :

```
numcols = (xmax-xmin) 
numrows = (ymax-ymin) 
x_steps = complex(str(numcols) + "j")
y_steps = complex(str(numrows) + "j")
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:x_steps, ymin:ymax:y_steps]
```

And it's not working either, any ideas?

Note that my data (lat and lon) are stored in lists.

Comment: Could you include a sample what the result should look like? At least the first few elements of `x` and `y`. Please don't forget to include `xmin`, `xmax`, etc. (have a look at [mcve] to see what is expected of a good question)

Answer (score 1):

For illustration purposes I'm just doing the 1d case

```
In [285]: xmin, xmax = 0, 10 
In [286]: xcol = (xmax-xmin)*10
In [287]: np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:(xcol*1j)]
Out[287]: 
array([  0.        ,   0.1010101 ,   0.2020202 ,   0.3030303 ,
         0.4040404 ,   0.50505051,   0.60606061,   0.70707071,
         0.80808081,   0.90909091,   1.01010101,   1.11111111,
         ...
         9.6969697 ,   9.7979798 ,   9.8989899 ,  10.        ])
In [288]: len(_)
Out[288]: 100
```

The complex step approach works for me.  `mgrid` translates that into a `linspace` expression, `np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)`

I was going to suggest the non-j approach,

```
In [290]: np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:.1]
Out[290]: 
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,
        1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,
        ....  9.4,  9.5,  9.6,  9.7,  9.8,
        9.9])
```

But it translates the expression into a `np.arange(xmin, xmax, .1)` and does handle the end point as nicely.

You may want to tweak the count to get a clean step; for example to step by .1, we want to increase the count from 100 to 101.

```
xcol = (xmax-xmin)*10+1
In [294]: np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xcol)
Out[294]: 
array([  0. ,   0.1,   0.2,   0.3,   0.4,   0.5,   0.6,   0.7,   0.8,       
         ...   9.7,   9.8, 9.9,  10. ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but in general there are two ways to define the step:

- You pass in a real number (float, int) that's the **step width**
- You pass in a complex number that's the **number of steps**

If you want 100 elements you pass in `100j`, if you want a step width of `1` you pass in `1` (or because it's the default you can also omit it).

You can always convert them into one another with:

```
def stepwidth(mini, maxi, nsteps):
    return (maxi - mini) / (nsteps - 1)

def nsteps(mini, maxi, stepwidth):
    return (maxi - mini) / stepwidth + 1
```

---

It seems to me that you're calculations are wrong:

```
>>> xmin = 100
>>> xmax = 200
>>> (xmax-xmin) * 100 * 1j
10000j
```

That means you get a 10000 * 10000 array as result. If you wanted one array point in the grid for each integer simply use:

```
>>> x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:1, ymin:ymax:1]
```

Or if you want 100 points between integer (like the multiplication with `100`) use:

```
>>> x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:0.01, ymin:ymax:0.01]
```

It doesn't really make sense to define the **number of grid points** based on the minimum and maximum point of your grid. But that's exactly what you did and it worked correctly, I just think you mistook **step width** and **number of steps** there.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers, but my main question is how to insert a  variable step into numpy.mgrid while : variable step  = (xmax-xmin)*100

Comment: Then you need to be more specific. Include a short self-contained example including the desired output vs. what you got. What you did was correct - it probably just wasn't what you wanted (or you exhausted your memory when you tried to get the two 10000x10000 arrays in your first example).

Comment: I have a csv file containing (lat, lon, value)  and I am trying to plot a density map using kernel density estimation , in other terms i need to calculate the number of values per km2, thta's why i need to define my step variable as mentionned before.

Comment: @MarieAntoinette But then just use a step value of 1 [km] (like I showed in `np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:1, ymin:ymax:1]`).

Comment: 1j stands for 1km ?

Comment: Forget about the `j`, you want to specify the step width so you **mustn't use** complex steps (re-read the first sentences of my answer!). Just use `np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:1, ymin:ymax:1]`. There is no unit support in NumPy, so you need to convert your lat/lon to kilometers or the `mgrid` to lat/lon. But that's a different question altogether.

Comment: when i did np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:1, ymin:ymax:1], it gave me  a very pixelated and fuzzy image  !

Comment: @MarieAntoinette What about the second solution: `np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:0.01, ymin:ymax:0.01]`?

Comment: i did np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:0.01, ymin:ymax:0.01] , but it's not giving me any results it remains on the execution without saying anything for minutes ...may be i am exhausting the memory as you said ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following will achieve what you want to do:

```
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:complex(0,100), ymin:ymax:complex(0,100)]
```

To use a variable as the number of steps, replace the constant 100 in the above expression with an integer variable. e.g.

```
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:complex(0,i), ymin:ymax:complex(0,k)]
```

where `i` and `k` are integers.

Comment: Hi Mike Lees, thanks for contributing your first answer! May I suggest you edit your answer to properly style the code blocks. Also, I would suggest refraining from editorial comments about how you found the post and focus on the answer. This helps make your answer easier to read and search for. Thanks again for your contribution!